# Javascript - Calculate number of days between two weekdays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

I looking for a function that calculate the day difference between two weekdays. Like, for eg.

Monday - Friday = 4 
Sunday - Saturday = 6

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create an object with the weekdays' values.

Let's call it `weekdays`. The purpose of this object is to keep the value for every day from a week.

Then just create an algorithm in order to find out the **difference**.

```js
var weekdays = {
       "Monday" : 1,
       "Tuesday" : 2,
       "Wednesday" : 3,
       "Thursday" : 4,
       "Friday" : 5,
       "Saturday" : 6,
       "Sunday" : 7
}

getBetweenWeekDays = function(day1, day2){
   if(weekdays[day1] <= weekdays[day2])
     return weekdays[day2] - weekdays[day1];
   return 7 - weekdays[day1] + weekdays[day2];
};
console.log('Monday - Friday = ' + getBetweenWeekDays('Monday','Friday')); 
console.log('Sunday - Saturday = ' + getBetweenWeekDays('Sunday','Saturday'));
console.log('Wednesday - Tuesday = ' + getBetweenWeekDays('Wednesday','Tuesday'));
console.log('Tuesday - Wednesday = ' + getBetweenWeekDays('Tuesday','Wednesday'));
```